# Why is an execv slower than a printf after a fork in a c program?

Tags: c, printf, ls, execv

Say I have the following program called program.c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int function(char **argv) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
    execv(*argv, argv); 
    }
    
    int value=0;
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int return2;
    
    return2 = function(argv+1);
    printf("%d\n", return2);
}
```

And I execute `./program /bin/ls`, why is the ls executed after the `printf` of return2?

Example : `./program /bin/ls`

returns

```
0 
file1
file2
file3
```

It's not about the newline character(buffer related) because the behavior is the same even if I remove the \n from the printf.

I would expect the execv to print the `ls` immediately, before the child process had the time to reach the `printf`.

Comment: For future questions, please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You need to explain the expected behavior inside your question body, as well as the actual behavior. My answer is really just *guessing* about the problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of the variables `result` and `value`?

Comment: The ```result``` variable was useless, the ```value``` variable is to test which is the fastest, the ```execv``` or the ```printf```. It just represents a value to print.

Comment: But you're not really measuring the time of the `execv` call itself, you're measuring your little ans quick program against the full `ls` program which is going to be rather slow (by order of magnitudes).

Comment: OT: regaarding: `return2 = function(argv+1);`  do not access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the command line parameter.  Otherwise the access to `argv[1]` will be accessing a NULL value

Comment: regarding: `if (pid > 0) {
    execv(*argv, argv);`  this is performing the call to `execv()` in the parent process rather than the child process.  Also, `fork()` has three kinds of return values: <0 means an error occurred.  ==0 means in the child process.  >0 means in the parent process.  The code should be checking for all three conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parent process doesn't wait for the child process to exit, it will return from `function` back to `main` immediately after the `fork` call, and then `main` will finish up what it does immediately as well.

It might even be that the parent process finishes before the child process even gets to run.

Use [`wait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) (or related functions) to wait for the child process to exit, and to be able to get its exit code.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. checks for errors and reports them
3. performs the desired functionality
4. parent process waits for the child to complete

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int function(char **argv) 
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) 
    {  // then child process
        execv(*argv, argv); 
        perror( "execv failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    if( pid < 0 )
    {
        perror( "fork failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    
    //if( pid > 0 )
    // then parent process
    int status;
    waitpid( pid, &status, 0 );
        

    return status;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int return2;
    
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s cmdToRun\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    return2 = function(argv+1);
    printf("%d\n", return2);
}
```